# Should OLAP cubes always be built upon a data warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, cube

I have a OLTP database that I want to do complex analyses of its data. I recently learned about OLAP cubes and SQL Server Analysis Services. Building a cube for analyzing the data seems like the right way to go.

However, when looking through the [Microsoft SSAS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services-tutorial-scenario), I wasn't able to clarify whether the cube is only meant to be built upon data warehouses or OLTP databases. I realize that a data warehouse could be as simple as a database (like I have). If I want to build a cube, will I have to create a warehouse of what I currently have? Should I even be thinking about data warehousing? Both seem like must-haves for data analysis.

Comment: Data warehouses are certainly very useful, and it is true that SSAS will work very well from them.
However, what is most useful to know is that SSAS does best when the data is structured as 'facts' recording numerical information, surrounded by 'dimensions' to give context to those facts.
If you want to avoid the data warehouses step in your situation, it might be that you could create views over your OLTP data to feed your SSAS cubes.

Comment: Thank you! This clarified things quite a bit. We were already headed in the direction of building views over the OLTP data. So for now, I'll try that approach. And if its decided that a data warehouse is ever needed, it wouldn't be too much extra work to go back.